How to update list of files in README
have a repository containing the README.md, and a folder called sd/. In this folder are a bunch of files; I'd like to extract a list of those whose names follow the pattern sd_YYY-MM-DD.md, and update the readme with this list of files in reverse chronological order (newest first), so that the readme looks like:
[the usual content of the readme]
    
# Current files
    
[21/11/2024](sd/sd_2024-11-21.md)

etc.

I've managed to work out that my regex should be /sd_\d{4}(-\d{2}){2}\.md/gm, and I think the way to use this is in the command
find sd/ -regex "/sd_\d{4}(-\d{2}){2}\.md/gm"

but I can't work out how to extract the date from this, much less how to update a list in the readme (rather than appending every time).
My best attempt at setting up the workflow is as follows:
name: update-sd-list
on: [push]
jobs:
  get-file-list-and-write-to-readme:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: [?????????]

Maybe I also need to commit the change?
Stack Overflow suggests README has failed to update using Github Action which is close to what I want but I don't understand it well enough to modify it to my needs (and it doesn't include the getting-the-date part).

Given the date format in the filenames, a glob will expand them in ascending order, so you could build the list of new links with something like this:
printf '%s\n' sd/sd_*-*-*.md |
tac |
awk -F '[_.-]' '{printf("[%s/%s/%s](%s)\n", $4,$3,$2,$0)}'

Now, updating README.md depends on the exact structure of the file, but skipping the old links and adding the new ones after the # Current files line should be enough here:
# previous_commands |
awk '
    NR == 1 {
        fileLinks = $0;
        next;
    }
    $0 == "# Current files" {
        printf("%s\n\n%s", $0, fileLinks);
        next;
    }
    /\(sd\/sd_.*\.md\)/ { next } # skip old links
    { print }
' RS= - RS='\n' README.md > README.md.new    # && mv README.md.new README.md

Then, how you'll add the above code in your workflow is up to you.

ASIDE
Here's an other solution, POSIX compliant, with a single call to awk:
printf '%s\n' sd/sd_*-*-*.md |
sort -r |
awk -F '[_.-]' '
    # process STDIN stream
    FNR == NR {
        links[++nbLinks] = sprintf("[%s/%s/%s](%s)", $4,$3,$2,$0);
        next;
    }
    # process README.md file
    $0 == "# Current files" {
        print;
        for (i = 1; i <= nbLinks; i++)
          printf("\n%s", links[i]);
        next;
    }
    /\(sd\/sd_.*\.md\)/ { next }
    { print }
' - README.md > README.md.tmp &&
mv README.md.tmp README.md


Thank you! Just to clarify, this is searching for the heading # Current files and overwriting everything that comes after it, right? Or should I be careful for something else in the readme?

@confusedandbemused To be exact, it inserts the new links after each line that starts with # Current files and deletes the lines that contained (sd/sd_*.md). The rest isn't modified.
